# Angular 2 Post updates my list but doesn't change the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am using Angular2 and MVC. I am following along with a lot of the tutorial on angular.io but changing some things to implement my own solution. Basically I have a table that shows clients and their identifier number. Using mock data, I was able to retrieve the clients and add new ones. The new ones would update my clientList and show the new client in my display table.

Once I started converting this to hit the server to get and post the data, I started to have issues.

I am able to retrieve the data perfectly fine from the server and it gives me the output I expect. When I try to post a new one to the server, it goes into my post method perfectly fine. It pushes the value into my clientList, but doesnt update my display table.

I'd like to add that I am not actually adding the data to my list on the server side, I am simply just returning a new object to try to get it to update my view.

Here's my service:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Client} from './client';
import {RequestOptions, Http, Response, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
constructor(private http: Http) { }


getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.http.get('/Client/GetClients')
        .map(this.extractData);
}

addClient(client: Client): Observable<Client> {
    let clientUrl = '/Client/AddClient';
    let body = JSON.stringify({ client });
    let header = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });

    return this.http.post(clientUrl, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}
private handleError(error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
}
```

My app component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'Scripts/typescript/app.component.html',
directives: [ClientFormComponent, MODAL_DIRECTIVES],
providers: [ClientService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private _clientService: ClientService) { }

currentClient: Client;
@ViewChild('modal')
modal: ModalComponent;
public clients: Client[];
public errorMessage: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients();
}

getClients() {
    this._clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => this.clients = clients, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}

deleteClient() {
    var index = this.clients.indexOf(this.currentClient, 0);
    if (index > -1) {
        this.clients.splice(index, 1)
    }
}

close() {
    this.modal.close();
}

open(client: Client) {
    this.currentClient = client;
    this.modal.open();
```

And my component with the call to the service when I click an add button:

```
@Component({
selector: 'client-form',
templateUrl: 'Scripts/typescript/client-form.component.html'
})
export class ClientFormComponent
 {
constructor(private _clientService: ClientService) { }
@Input() clientList;
model = <Client>{ name: 'Bob', npi: 12345678 };
submitted = false;
active = true;
errorMessage: string;

onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }    

ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients();
}

getClients() {
    this._clientService.getClients()
        .subscribe(
        clients => this.clientList = clients,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}

addClient() {        
    this._clientService.addClient(this.model)
        .subscribe(
        client => this.clientList.push(client),
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
}
```

Here is my template for displaying the table, which is the app.component.html:

```html
<h1>Client/NPI Cross Reference</h1>
<client-form></client-form>
<table class="table">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
        <td>Client</td>
        <td>NPI</td>
        <td>Date Added</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="#client of clients;">
        <td>{{client.name}}</td>
        <td>{{client.npi}}</td>
        <td>{{client.dateAdded}}</td>
        <td>
            <span style="color: red;  font-size: 16px; cursor: pointer;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" (click)="open(client)"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<modal #modal [animation]="animationsEnabled" (onClose)="deleteClient()" (onDismiss)="dismissed()">
    <modal-header [show-close]="true">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>
        Are you sure you want to delete this entry?
    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal.close()">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modal.dismiss()">No</button>
    </modal-footer>
</modal>
```

Here is my form template html:

```html
<div class="container">
    <form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #clientForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group" style="float: left;">
            <label for="clientid">Client Id:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.name" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm" #newClient>
            <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                Name is required
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
            <label for="npi">NPI:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.npi" ngControl="npi" #newNpi>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin: 25px 0 0 10px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addClient()" [disabled]="!clientForm.form.valid">Add</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

On the server side, I am simply just returning a json client:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddClient()
    {

        var client = new Models.Client();
        client.name = "test";
        client.npi = 12345;
        client.dateAdded = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        return Json(client);
    }
```

When using the mock data, it would automatically update my table and I'd be able to see my new client in the table. But now that I am using the server, it adds it to the clientList, but it doesnt actually change the view of my table.

How can I get it to change my table and update it to show it's been added?

Comment: Could you provide the way you display your table? Thanks!

Comment: Added the html for both templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the point is that you are calling twice the method `getClients()` of your `ClientService`, once from the the `AppComponent` and once from the `ClientFormComponent`.

This means that you will get 2 different arrays, one held in the `AppComponent` and one held in the `ClientFormComponent`.

If what I say is correct, then when you add a new client via the POST command, then the `ClientFormComponent` updates its array but this has no effect on the `AppComponent` array (which is a different object).

The solution in this case is probably:

1) make the `AppComponent` pass its `clients` array to the `ClientFormComponent` such as `<client-form [clientList]="clients"></client-form>` (which is probably the reason why `clientList` is preceded by `@Input()`)

2) Avoid like hell resetting the `clientList` from within the `ClientFormComponent` (which is currently happening in the line `this.clientList = clients`)

I hope I am not missing something and that this can help.

PS: I guess you do not need @Injectable() in the AppComponent, since it is a Component

Comment: I changed this and it works now, but it's weird because this was working EXACTLY the way I have it before I started trying to do a post to the server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is happening. When you call `getClients()` inside `ClientFormComponent`, it replaces the `clientsList` with a new array. But, the one in the view is the array assigned by `getClients()` inside `AppComponent`. One way to make sure is to comment the line inside `ClientFormComponent`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //this.getClients();
}
```

Comment: I commented it out and am still having the same problem. It worked perfectly fine before I started trying to get data from and post data to the server, like the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial on angular.io did with "mock-clients" instead of the "mock-heroes" that they used.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Angular2, but before it felt like the "clients" and "clientList" in both components were linked together. Now it feels disconnected or something.

Comment: @Bohms27 In `<client-form></client-form>` change it to `<client-form [clientList]="clients"></client-form>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

> public clients: Client[];

to

> public clients: Client[] = [];